# Как протестировать класс, запускающий внутри метода Handler

Tags: java, android, junit, mvp, android-handler

Имеется презентер. Внутри одного из методов создается и запускается Handler, для отложенного задания.

```
public void myMethode() {
     ...........
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    run(){
      ...
    } 
  }, 2000
)
```

Как проверить работу метода run? У меня получается, что он не стартует в тесте вообще.

Comment: Можно сделать класс неанонимным и протестировать его метод как обычно

Comment: То есть сделать его еще и public? Ведь иначе к нему не будет доступа извне или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Можно сделать его `package-private`